# visualization of keyboard shortcut alt escape

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate

Just found I can use <kbd>alt+Escape</kbd> to switch between programs that are not minimized.

Is there a way of getting a visualization of the open programs I can switch between using <kbd>Alt+Escape</kbd> eg the same way I get using <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>?